# Can I change how Visual Studio 2008 comments selection?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I know that **C-k C-c** comments a selection, and currently it works as thus in C++:

```
AwesomeCode();
MoreAwesomeCode();

//AwesomeCode();
//MoreAwesomeCode();
```

However, I would like it to comment it as such:

```
// AwesomeCode();
// MoreAwesomeCode();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Visual Studio macro and define your own block comment string, in this case two forward slashes followed by a space.  Here's a codeguru.com that might help you get started:

[Block Comment Macro for Visual Studio .NET](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_general/ideincludingvisualstudionet/article.php/c6085)